# How to combine two 2D array into the following in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Suppose I have 2 2D array as follows:

```
A = [[1, 2],
     [3, 4]]

B = [[5, 6, 7],
     [8, 9, 8],
     [7, 6, 5]]
```

Is there a numpy function to combine A and B into C as follows?

```
C = [[1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
     [3, 4, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 5, 6, 7],
     [0, 0, 8, 9, 8],
     [0, 0, 7, 6, 5]]
```

Thanks

Comment: Would it kill you to put quotes around the strings? Makes it that much harder to copy and run.

Comment: The best way, would obviously being trying to code a solution. In fact, you should try it. Or show at least what you tried, where it did not work and what your exact problem is. We help you out to solve your codes problems, in general we do not provide full fledged solutions.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your reply. I have no problem crafting this solution from scratch, but I am looking for a numpy function that does just that rather than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you expect to be making many linear algebraic operations, [NumPy](https://www.numpy.org)/[SciPy](https://scipy.org) will be your friend. For the particular problem of creating block diagonal matrices, [`scipy.linalg.block_diag`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.block_diag.html) saves the day:

```
In [14]: from scipy.linalg import block_diag

In [16]: A = [[1, 2],
    ...:      [3, 4]]
    ...:

In [17]: B = [[5, 6, 7],
    ...:      [8, 9, 60],
    ...:      [10, 20, 0]]
    ...:

In [18]: block_diag(A, B)
Out[18]:
array([[ 1,  2,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 3,  4,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 0,  0,  8,  9, 60],
       [ 0,  0, 10, 20,  0]], dtype=int32)
```

Otherwise (edit: noting that the question in its original form did not actually specify that the desired solution involved NumPy), if you just want to do it with vanilla Python, assuming that all blocks are square you could do something like

```
[a + [0]*len(B) for a in A] + [[0]*len(A) + b for b in B]
```

Comment: Thanks. "scipy.linalg.block_diag()" is what I looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop your own program to do that, shouldn't be too difficult.

Here are some starting steps:

1. Front append 0's in all elemnts of A and back append 0's in all elements of B to make their lengths equal.
2. Then simply fill in the values of A and B in the resulting matrix.