# Concat DataFrames diagonally

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

This is a self answered question. Given two dataFrames,

```
x
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4

y
   0  1  2
0  5  6  7
1  8  9  X
2  Y  Z  0
```

The diagonal concatenation of x and y is given by:

```
     0    1    3    4    5
0  1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  3.0  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN    5    6    7
3  NaN  NaN    8    9    X
4  NaN  NaN    Y    Z    0
```

What is the easiest and simplest way of doing this? I would like to consider two cases:

1. concatenating two dataFrames
2. concatenating an unspecified number of dataFrames (list of DataFrames)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the simple case. Assuming both the headers and indexes are monotonically numeric, you can just modify `y`'s indexers as offsets from `x`:

```
y.index += x.index[-1] + 1
y.columns += x.columns[-1] + 1   

pd.concat([x, y])

     0    1    2    3    4
0  1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  3.0  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN    5    6    7
3  NaN  NaN    8    9    X
4  NaN  NaN    Y    Z    0
```

Now, to generalise this to multiple DataFrames, we iterate over a loop:

```
df_list = [x, y]

offset_x = offset_y = 0
for df in df_list:
    df.index = np.arange(len(df)) + offset_x
    df.columns = np.arange(len(df.columns)) + offset_y

    offset_x += df.index[-1] + 1
    offset_y += df.columns[-1] + 1

pd.concat(df_list)

     0    1    2    3    4
0  1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  3.0  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN    5    6    7
3  NaN  NaN    8    9    X
4  NaN  NaN    Y    Z    0
```

If either your index/columns are not monotonically increasing, I strongly suggest resetting them before concatenating, or look into the option below.

---

If you're okay with 0s instead of NaNs, you can use `scipy`'s `block_diag` without having to modify either the indices or columns:

```
from scipy.linalg import block_diag
pd.DataFrame(block_diag(*df_list))

   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  2  0  0  0
1  3  4  0  0  0
2  0  0  5  6  7
3  0  0  8  9  X
4  0  0  Y  Z  0
```

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50659544/4909087) for this solution.

Comment: This seems to happen all the time when I *don't* want it to. It's surprisingly hard to arrange when you do :)

Comment: @unutbu not particularly hard, just tedious ;-) but I know that feeling...

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to @coldpeed's `scipy.linalg` solution, you can easily manipulate the `block_diag` algorithm to use a custom fill value.

Here's a simplified version:

```
import numpy as np

def block_diag(*arrs, fillval=0):

    arrs = [np.atleast_2d(a) for a in arrs]

    shapes = np.array([a.shape for a in arrs])
    out_dtype = np.find_common_type([arr.dtype for arr in arrs], [])
    out = np.full(np.sum(shapes, axis=0), fill_value=fillval, dtype=out_dtype)

    r, c = 0, 0
    for i, (rr, cc) in enumerate(shapes):
        out[r:r + rr, c:c + cc] = arrs[i]
        r += rr
        c += cc
    return out

df_list = [df1, df2]

res = pd.DataFrame(block_diag(*df_list, fillval=np.nan))

print(res)

     0    1    2    3    4
0    1    2  NaN  NaN  NaN
1    3    4  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN    5    6    7
3  NaN  NaN    8    9    X
4  NaN  NaN    Y    Z    0
```

We needed only to add an extra optional parameter and modify the following line, which previous utilised `np.zeros`:

```
out = np.full(np.sum(shapes, axis=0), fill_value=fillval, dtype=out_dtype)
```